# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '' . in the same folder

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two python files(qq.py and ww.py) are in the same folder.

code in qq.py is:

```
print('123x')
```

code in ww.py is:

```
import qq
```

when I execute ww.py in CMD, the error was appered:
Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "ww.py", line 1, in <module>
import qq ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qq'
```

I don't know if there are some configuration errors.
It would be great If someone can help me work through this issue.

This is my python version.

```
Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkFTZ.png)

Comment: Did you try `from . import qq`?

Comment: when I type 'from . import qq' ,It was like this:    from . import qq
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Comment: In order to do relative imports, you need to be within a module. It is as simple as creating an __ init __.py file (without the spaces) in the same directory as your code

Comment: Could you showcase the files and the document folder?

Comment: Did you post the full code for both qq.py and ww.py? It seems like you are using qq as a function.

Comment: Quick question, where are you running the python file from? Are you changing directory to the folder where all of the python files are? I suspect that maybe you are running python from outside of the folder. When you run python, it sets the current working directory to the directory you are in when you run python. When importing, it looks at the current working directory to find if the file is there, and anywhere the the PATH variable indicates. Try changing to the folder with the files in them.

Comment: Hi will, I have posted the full code for both qq.py and ww.py. I just want to test if I can import my own code. But it failed, even in the same folder.

Comment: Can you check if the current directory is going into the PYTHONPATH. Try running `import sys` and `print(*sys.path, sep="\n")`. You don't have to give the result, just curious if the folder is printed.

Comment: Hi Misha, this is the result: '

    C:\Users\Edward\projects\xyz>python
    Python 3.8.1 (tags/v3.8.1:1b293b6, Dec 18 2019, 23:11:46) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import sys
    >>> print(*sys.path, sep='\n')
    C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\personal\python-3.8.1-embed-amd64\python38.zip
    C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\personal\python-3.8.1-embed-amd64
    C:\Users\Edward\Desktop\personal\python-3.8.1-embed-amd64\lib\site-packages'

Comment: I meant from ww.py, as I mentioned previously, python stores where to look for modules in`PYTHONPATH` (previously I said PATH, but looked into it and saw that python uses it's own variable for modules.). You can access this using the mentioned `sys.path`. What I'm trying to figure out is if ww.py is adding the folder to `PYTHONPATH` or not (I am not entirely sure if python looks in the folder without adding, but when I run it, it adds the folder). Want to know what ww.py sees as `PYTHONPATH`

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the code in ww.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
import qq
```

now, ww.py can run well

Comment: This works fine, but I'm still curious as to why it wasn't adding the path by default. I think if you have time later, it's work investigating

Comment: Thanks, Misha, you are right, this is only a temporary solution.
I suspect I've misconfigured something